# Doxygen - selectively remove links for example programs?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am using Doxygen for a library of C++ utilities that I need to distribute.  I have figured out how to include example programs in my Doxygen output, and my Class pages are able to automatically link to the desired examples.

```
/** \example example_Exception.cpp */
```

Unfortunately, Doxygen also generates links on my Class page to *every* example program that makes use of it, rather than just the one I specify.  My Exception class is the worst offender, since all of my examples make use of it.  As a result, the documentation page for my Exception class includes a link to each and every example program.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: You can specify the source files that are included in your doxygen run.  Where do the example programs reside?  Can you eliminate them in source file list?

Comment: @AnonMail -Thanks for the suggestion. I still need to keep them in the source list, since all of my example programs do need to end up in the final documentation package with their own page.  I just don't want my class page for Exception to link to each and every one of them.